# accessing url parameter using jstl

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I am new to jstl and I need help getting a url-string parameter on a jsp that also contains EL markup from an iterated list of objects retrieved from a database.  Can someone show me how to fix the code below so that the following line of code populates with an actual number where I am asking for `${param.spid}:`

```
<a href="create-course-summary?spid="${param.spid}>add</a>
```

Here is the background:

I am calling a servlet with the following url pattern:

```
view-course-summaries?spid=1
```

This calls the following `doGet` method in a servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
   throws ServletException, IOException {
    String spidString = req.getParameter("spid");
    Long spid = new Long(spidString);
    List<CourseSummary> coursesummaries = new CourseSummaryDAO().findAllCS(spid);
    req.setAttribute("coursesummaries", coursesummaries);
    jsp.forward(req, resp);
}
```

And returns the following jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ include file="admintop.inc" %>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Name of School (Course Provider):</td>
  <td>will go here</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>
<a href="create-course-summary?spid="${param.spid}>add</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan=2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>id</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach varStatus="loopCounter" items="${coursesummaries}" var="coursesummary">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${coursesummary.coursetype}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${coursesummary.numunits}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${coursesummary.id}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>   

<%@ include file="adminbottom.inc" %>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href='create-course-summary?spid=${param["spid"]}'>add</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think my placement of the quotes was part of the problem, also.  +1 and credit for accepted answer.  Nice response time.